# How to step back to previous frame in Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

Suppose below Code.

```
void CurrentFrame()
{
  cout<<"I am here"<<endl; //currently break point at this
   ...
   ...
   ...
}
int main()
{
   ...
  ...
  CurrentFrame();
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

How can i jump to previous frame in main from the current breakpoint in CurrentFrame function.

Comment: any update about this issue, please check if my answer helps you handle the issue or not. If it helps, please do not forget to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). And if not, please feel free to let us know:)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your definition of "jump". If you want to know where the current function was called from, then you are looking for the **Call Stack**. By default it should be visible at the bottom right when a breakpoint hits. If however you mean to execute the code until the current function is done and returned from, then just hit **Shift + F11**.

Comment: Main purpose is , Once i reached this function . I came to know something wrong has happened , So want to return to previous function from where this was called and want to debug that by going to some instructions back in that function..

Comment: @Sanjeev: That description is still ambiguous, mostly because Visual Studio has a _very_ good debugger. It even has a "back in time" debugger: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/step-back-while-debugging-with-intellitrace/

Answer (score 0):

Under your situation, right-click on the line you want to roll back, and then click **Set Next Statement**, and then you will return back to the previous line. It will not continue to execute the remaining abnormal function code pieces and it just stop that.

[image]